# Parsing HTTP POST request or how to find a string in a byte array

Tags: string-manipulation, binary, unicode, http-functions

I am a developer of a Mathematica web-server (see [TinyWEB](https://github.com/JerryI/tinyweb-mathematica)). I managed to parse a multipart POST request containing text files, however, it is hard to expand it to any types of binary data like JPEG, PNG files.

The problem is hiding in the specification of POST request. Here is an example

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.example
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="boundary"

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"

value1
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"; filename="example.txt"

value2
--boundary--
```

To fetch the content we need to find this particular pattern "--boundary" which is always an id of a field. Therefore we need to analyze the incoming data as

```
    While[TrueQ[(string = ReadString[stream, "--" <> bondary]) != "--\r\n"] && ! TrueQ[string == EndOfFile],
       (*do the extraction of the data*)
        
    ];
```

Of course when have a binary data PNG or JPEG, we will ended up with an error like

> $CharacterEncoding::utf8: The byte sequence {137} could not be
> interpreted as a character in the UTF-8 character encoding.

The obvious answer is to forget about it and just handle the data as a ByteArray without conversion to a string.

The next question is more general - what will be the best strategy to find a string pattern or a sequence of characters inside a ByteArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Latin1 encoding, or define your own
[image]